# How to show one more item than FirestorePagingAdapter's list size at the beginning of a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a recyclerview with `FirestorePagingAdapter` to display some documents from a Firestore collection. I need to show an extra item as a header(for which data does not come from the adapter). For simplicity let us assume I have only one view type and a header. So my `getItemViewType()` method would look like this.

```
@override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position==0) return ViewType.HEADER;
    else return ViewType.BODY_ITEM;
}
```

Inside `onBindViewHolder()` I am doing this

```
@override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final MyModel model) {
    if(holder instanceof HeaderHolder){
        holder.bind();
        return;
    }
    // because first item from adapter is shown at recyclerview's second position
    // based on the assumption that the parameter 'position' is recyclerview's position
    DocumentSnapshot mDocumentSnapshot = this.getCurrentList().get(position-1);
    holder.bindTo(mDocumentSnapshot);
}
```

So I have overrode the `getItemCount()` method like this

```
@override
public int getItemCount() {
    // because there is one extra header
    return super.getItemCount()+1;
}
```

But doing so causes my app to crash and the following error message is logged

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Item count is zero, getItem() call is invalid
        at android.arch.paging.AsyncPagedListDiffer.getItem(AsyncPagedListDiffer.java:194)
        at android.arch.paging.PagedListAdapter.getItem(PagedListAdapter.java:156)
        at com.firebase.ui.firestore.paging.FirestorePagingAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirestorePagingAdapter.java:128)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
```

(only first few lines)
I have 12 documents in my firestore collection.
If I don't override the `getItemCount()` method then 12 items are shown by the recyclerview including the header. The last document is fetched by the adapter but not shown by the recyclerview. But overriding the `getItemCount()` method makes the app crash(as mentioned above).

I have read(at least tried to read :)) the source code for `AsyncPagedListDiffer`, `PagedListAdapter` and `FirestorePagingAdapter`..
The exception `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Item count is zero, getItem() call is invalid` is thrown by `AsyncPagedListDiffer`'s `getItem()` method.

```
private PagedList<T> mPagedList;
private PagedList<T> mSnapshot;
.......................
.......................
.......................
public T getItem(int index) {
    if (mPagedList == null) {
        if (mSnapshot == null) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "Item count is zero, getItem() call is invalid");
        } else {
            return mSnapshot.get(index);
        }
    }

    mPagedList.loadAround(index);
    return mPagedList.get(index);
    }
```

**Now why is this exception generated??How can I solve this?? What are the alternatives to my approach for adding a header(again data shown by this does not come from the adapter) to a recyclerview.**

**Also is the parameter 'position' supplied to `onBindViewHolder()` actually adapter's positon or recyclerviews position to add a new item**(The documentation calls this adapters position but I am not sure)

Answer (score 0):

You have to ALSO override the superclass `FirestorePagingAdapter`'s `onBindViewHolder` and add the logic inside it as shown.

```
    @override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         if(position != 0){
             super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position - 1)
         }
    }
```

The superclass `FirestorePagingAdapter`'s `onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)` is called for every single item in the recycler view. When you have added +1 to the `itemCount`, when the recyclerview reaches the last position, it ends up with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because the results of the database query is stored as a `List` in the `PagedStorage` class with the size `itemCount`.

With this your implementation of the `FirestorePagingAdapter` should have 2 `onBindViewHolder` methods.